# How to create Windows Service from CMD and pass MinIO arguments to it?

Tags: cmd, windows-services, minio

I'm using MinIO, and I can run it via CMD using following command:

```
minio.exe server C:\MinIO
```

I need to create a Windows Service for MinIO using in-built Windows methods or soft from Microsoft site - for example, "sc create" command.
But I cannot create this service for MinIO with specified arguments - when I run new service, I have an error or endless loading with error.

I tried:

```
sc create MinIO binpath= "C:\MinIO\minio.exe server C:\MinIO"
sc create MinIO binpath= "C:\MinIO\minio.exe --server C:\MinIO"
```

Changed ImagePath in Register to:

```
C:\MinIO\minio.exe server C:\MinIO
C:\MinIO -server C:\MinIO
C:\MinIO\minio.exe "server C:\MinIO
```

Maybe I missed something?

Comment: `sc create MinIO binpath= "C:\MinIO\minio.exe server C:\MinIO"` should had been ok. Could you give us the error message you get when launching the service in this case ?

Comment: @Zilog80 [Error: 1053] The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Comment: If I run same command that in binpath, in cmd - minio run perfectly

Comment: MinIO doesn't directly function as a service on Windows, you have to use WinSw wrapper for that. Check the documentation [here](https://github.com/minio/minio-service/tree/master/windows).

Comment: Yes, but service manager can install .exe files as services

Comment: And I need to use in-built or Microsoft soft from their site for that goal

Comment: Please create a startup script and add it or create a windows service application with .NET and start minio using that.

Comment: @AtlasPromotion Please add the correct answer if found and mark the question answered.